# Hangman Game in C

Tags: c

Hi Im working on a hangman program in C for my programming course and I have a problem. Below is the code where I have the problem:

```
char UserGuess;
int i, x;
int WrongGuesses;
for(i = 0; i < MAX_TRIES; i++ )
    printf("Go ahead and guess a letter\n");
    UserGuess = getchar();
    for (x = 0; x < len; x++)
        if (randomWordfomFile[x] = UserGuess)
            UserGuess = randomWordfromFile[x];
        else if
            break;

printf("%s", randomWordfromFile[]);
```

MAX_TRIES is a macro and randomWordfromFile is an array that I get from another function. (I can post the code for that function if required.

My problem is that I cant keep track of how many guesses the User got wrong and has left. Also if I want to add further functionality the loops inside loops make it harder as far as I can see. Is there an easier method or is this the best way to do it?

Comment: simple: `if (letter_is_in_word()) { correct++; } else { wrong++; } if ((correct + wrong) >= MAX_TRIES) { game_over(); }`

Comment: More than a few problems with this code. 1: it doesn't compile 2: use double equals in if statements, not single equals, 3: your printf should use randomWordfromFile not randomWordfromFile[].

Comment: Do I have to make another two functions called letter_is_in_word() and game_over()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was assignment instead..

```
 if (randomWordfomFile[x] == UserGuess)
```

Also you dont need `[]` in `printf()`

```
printf("%s", randomWordfromFile);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between assignment `=` operator and `==` operator.
Change

```
if (randomWordfomFile[x] = UserGuess)
```

to

```
if (randomWordfomFile[x] == UserGuess)
```

---

**Side Note:**
`getchar` return `int` type. Declare `UserGuess` as `int`

```
int UserGuess;
```

and change

```
printf("%s", randomWordfromFile[]);
```

to

```
printf("%s", randomWordfromFile);
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! Any recommendations for the rest of the code?

Comment: Why would the OP set UserGuess = randomWordfromFile[x] if randomWordfromFile[x] == UserGuess?

Comment: @jarmod; I don't know. o__O

Comment: Thanks! nothing else to change?

Comment: As @jarmod pointed that, if `randomWordfromFile[x] == UserGuess` then why you are doing `if randomWordfromFile[x] == UserGuessUserGuess = randomWordfromFile[x]`? It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @user2955782 At the moment your algorithm for the hangman game is not close to complete.  It would be good if you fleshed it out, then implemented it, and then came back with specific questions where you were having problems with the implementation.

Comment: @haccks Im doing that because in Hangman youre supposed to show where the letter is in the word so they can guess the rest of the word. So if the word is haccks and they guess "a" then theyre supposed to see -a-ccks

Comment: I just pointed out the mistakes you did in your snippet. Without knowing the algorithm of program I can't help you further.